Inconsistencies in detection and extraction of text using tesseract
I have provided the image from which I am trying to extract text from, using tesseract ocr.
Image for text detection
Along with that, I have also provided the result or the extracted text from the image.
Extracted text- result of tesseract ocr
As it can be observed from the images, the extracted text is not very accurate. Negative symbols have been omitted, some undesired characters are also there in the extracted text. (I have marked some of the incorrect results with blue boxes)
I have tried to improve the results by preprocessing and bringing changes in the parameters of the model. I have tried:

Binarizing the images
HDR processing of the processes

Even then, such inconsistencies remain.
How to improve the detection and extraction of text in tesseract? I have also tried paddleocr for the same task. Even then, symbols such as euro, some negative signs are not being detected.
I tried extracting text from the images and I want to extract the table and save it a csv. But the detected and extracted text is inaccurate.
